# How to get & display only 2nd level sub categories from a specific parent category

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

A Help. I want display sub categories from a specific parent category. For Example,

---

A

- AA

  -- AAA

  -- AAA
- BB

  -- BBB

  -- BBB

---

Assume, the above one is my concept. Now i want to display the all "2nd level sub categories (AAA, BBB) from parent category (A)". no need "AA & BB" category. If anyone give best solution to this?..

OR, kindly tell how can i add multiple categorizes in this "&child_of=19".....???

because, now i used the below code to display sub categories.

```
<?php
$subcategories = get_categories();
$subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=19&hide_empty&orderby=ID&order=DESC'); 
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
  echo sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
}
echo '</ul>';
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
<?php
    $subcategories = get_categories();
    $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=19&parent=19&hide_empty&orderby=ID&order=DESC'); 
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
      echo sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```